# How can I create a dashed line that slowly changes into a solid line in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I am trying to create a dashed line that initially has small dashes and large gaps between each dash. The dashes lengths should increase while the gaps decrease until the point is reached that the line becomes solid. Is there any way to do this other than manually drawing in the line lengths?

Comment: Hi tokun, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you need is a straight line, my first thought is to try to use the the blend tool on two horizontal lines, one short and one longer one. Like so:

[image: illustrator screen shot of Blend Options dialog box and a sequence of lengthening line segments]

Then fiddle with the exact segment length, stroke weight and the number of steps in the Blend Options dialog to get the effect you want. You may end up with overlapping lines and you'll have to join them and remove the extra anchor points.

And actually, I think you could apply this to a curved path, by Expanding the blend (with the entire blend object selected, go to Object --> Blend --> Expand), then drag the expanded group of lines to the Brushes panel and create a Pattern Brush.

Comment: I should've mentioned this in the original post, but I am trying to make a line with two 90 degree angles, like ' |______| '. I already tried blending and it didn't work, but your idea about expanding the blend and turning it into a brush worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do a horizontal [blend](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html) for example between a short dash and a longer dash, then play with all numeric values, the length of the lines, number of steps in the blend, etc. Probably other ways to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My approach was minorly labour-intensive, but nothing like as bad a "manually drawing in the line lengths" - I drew the entire path, set an initial dash + gap, then cut the curve at several points along its length - in each succeeding section, I incremented the gap down by 2 points, and the dash length up by 2 points.

Looked like this in the end:

[image]